# CSS: text box should respect left side div width

Tags: html, css

I have a structure that have a *title* and a *content*. And I like that the content respect the title width. Basically like that:

```
| Title:         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.  |
|                Praesent augue ex, dapibus quis vulputate ut, bibendum    |
|                vitae felis. Nunc tempor elit leo.                        |
|                                                                          |
| This is a long title:  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur           |
|                        adipiscing elit. Praesent augue ex, dapibus quis  |
|                        vulputate ut, bibendum vitae felis. Nunc tempor   |
|                        elit leo.                                         |
|                                                                          |
| <--                         PAGE WIDTH                               --> |
```

The *title* have `min-width: 100px; margin-right: 10px;`. *content* should use all available space that *title* isn't using.

My structure is something like that:

```
<div class="data">
    <div class="title">Some title:</div>
    <div class="value">Content.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Any specific reason to downvote it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with the css flexbox technique

```css
.data {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 10px;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
}

.title {
    min-width: 100px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.value {
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="data">
    <div class="title">Some title:</div>
    <div class="value">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam rhoncus risus quis quam elementum mollis. Aenean in egestas diam.</div>
</div>
<div class="data">
    <div class="title">Some other much longer title:</div>
    <div class="value">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam rhoncus risus quis quam elementum mollis. Aenean in egestas diam.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'll try use flexbox, but I don't know if it'll works fine on Safari, for instance.